# How to add tikz-cd diagrams together with the package "versions"?

Tags: tikz-cd, versions

I would like to know how to use tikz-cd inside a "processifversion" environment. Compiling the following code, I get an error message saying "Undefined control sequence."

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{versions,tikz-cd}
\includeversion{vi}
\excludeversion{ve}
\begin{document}Je 
    \processifversion{vi}{G
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[r] & B
\end{tikzcd}
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See section `3.4 Issues with active characters` of the tikz-cd documentation, which suggests:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{versions,tikz-cd}
\includeversion{vi}
\excludeversion{ve}
\begin{document}Je 
    \processifversion{vi}{G
\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
A \arrow[r] \& B
\end{tikzcd}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt answer!

Comment: @DougLiu You're welcome!